# Неправильная работа поддоменов

Tags: apache, httpd, freebsd, ispmanager

Подскажите плс, что может быть? На сервере 4 IP и есть сайты, один из них к примеру site.com. прошло время и поисковики начали ходить к нему как:

```
ns.site.comns1.site.comns2.site.commx.site.com
```

Соответственно произошло размытие контента. Вообщем создал я для них поодомены в ISPmanager, но как то глючно получилось. При заходе на ns.site.com открывается страничка то что надо, с надписью "ns".

Сайт ns1.site.com - опять же показывает эту же страничку "ns", хотя должен показывать страницу "ns1" с директории /site/ns1. Сайт ns2.site.com вообще выдает что "Сервер не найден". И сайт mx.site.com ведет себя, так же как и ns1.site.com, то есть выдает "ns", хотя должен "mx".

Записи с httpd.conf все правильно:

```
<VirtualHost 77.120.XXX.XXX:80>    ServerName mx.site.com    DocumentRoot /home/admin/data/www/site.com/mx    AssignUserID ...    CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ServerAlias www.mx.site.com    ServerAdmin ...</VirtualHost><VirtualHost 77.120.XXX.XXX:80>    ServerName ns2.site.com    DocumentRoot /home/admin/data/www/site.com/ns2    AssignUserID ...    CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ServerAlias www.ns2.site.com    ServerAdmin ...</VirtualHost><VirtualHost 77.120.XXX.XXX:80>    ServerName ns1.site.com    DocumentRoot /home/admin/data/www/site.com/ns1    AssignUserID ...    CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ServerAlias www.ns1.site.com    ServerAdmin ...</VirtualHost><VirtualHost 77.120.XXX.XXX:80>    ServerName ns.site.com    DocumentRoot /home/admin/data/www/site.com/ns    AssignUserID ...    CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/...    ServerAlias www.ns.site.com    ServerAdmin ...</VirtualHost>
```

в /var/named/etc/namedb/master/site.com

```
$TTL    3600site.com.   IN      SOA     ns1.site.com. root.site.com. (2011090258 10800 3600 604800 86400)site.com.   IN      NS       ns1.site.com.site.com.   IN      NS       ns2.site.com.site.com.   IN      MX      10 mailsite.com.   IN      MX      20 mailsite.com.   IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXwww     IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXftp     IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXmail    IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXsmtp    IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXpop     IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXsite.com.   IN      TXT      "v=spf1 ip4:77.120.XXX.XXX a mx ~all"www.ns1 IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXns      IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXwww.ns  IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXns1     IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXns2     IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXwww.ns2 IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXmx      IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXXwww.mx  IN      A        77.120.XXX.XXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неверно настроены dns. Точно не могу сказать что именно.

Comment: @ A 77.120.XXX.XXXwww A 77.120.XXX.XXX* A 77.120.XXX.XXX@ MX 10 site.com.ns1.registrator.comns2.registrator.comns3.registrator.com

Comment: @yarnik Эти записи прописаны для каждого ip?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Надо было всего лишь у регистратора указать свои нейм-сервера.